# Listbox items replace

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, replace, listbox

It's delete all listbox items text after question mark.
But I want to opposite. So, replace my listbox items text before question mark.

Example listbox item text:

```
 somethingpage?Iwantit
```

My code:

```
For i = cbox1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
     For x = cbox1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
         If cbox1.Items(i).ToString.Contains("?") Then
             Dim item = cbox1.Items(i).ToString()
             Dim pos = item.IndexOf("?")
             item = item.Substring(0, pos)
             cbox1.Items(i) = item

         End If
     Next
```

Comment: why u are using double for loop

Comment: Are you just wanting to replace all the text before the "?" OR all the text before the "?" AND "?" ...I am a little confused.

Comment: I want to replace all listbox items text before question mark. Example: Listbox item1: deleteit?Iwantit  Listbox item2: deleteit2?Iwantit2

Comment: @sandor I noticed you tagged ListBox, but your code seems to be looking at ComboBox as per your naming convention, did you just name your control that way? Also if you tested Visuals code did you throw an exception, I did as the index was out of range.

Comment: Answer updated! @Mr CoDeXeR: I had forgotten about that it can get index out of range. Thanks for reminding me :)

Comment: Just noticed, my function won't work 100% either. Today is not a good day to program for me. (;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay so here's a way to get this done without errors:

```
Dim FormattedString() As String
For i = cbox1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If cbox1.Items(i).ToString.Contains("?") Then
        Dim item = cbox1.Items(i).ToString()
        FormattedString = Split(item, "?", 2)
        cbox1.Items(i) = FormattedString(0)

    End If
Next
```

Comment: It's delete my listbox items text after quotation mark. I want to opposite.

Comment: Uuh, this should remove the text BEFORE the question mark. Did you try it?

Comment: You want the text before the ?. That's what your code seems to do already

Comment: No, my code delete my items text AFTER quotation mark.

Comment: How is that even possible since I made the code opposite? Yours should get the text before. Something is not right here... Have you tried removing one loop?

Comment: Please, try my code and u will see. It's delete after quotation mark. Example: something?it'sdeletefterqmarkbutIwantsomethingelse

Comment: I am not at home at the moment, I can try it in a couple of hours

Comment: @VisualVincent I'm throwing an exception with this code. Specifically in the: item.Remove(pos, item.Length - 1). The reason for this is because the index is off by 1...

Comment: Then I fix that when I'm home :)

Comment: @VisualVincent that's fine, please make sure as it can be misleading when other's come across this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
For i As Integer = 0 to cbox1.Items.Count - 1
    Dim sItem As String = cbox1.Items(i).ToString()

    If sItem.Contains("?") Then
        cbox1.Items(i) = sItem.Remove(0, sItem.IndexOf("?"))
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that uses `Regex` to fix your issue...

```
 Private lstObject As New List(Of Object) 'To hold your values

  Dim oObject As Object

    'Go through changing what we need to and then adding to our list
    For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        oObject = Regex.Replace(CStr(ListBox1.Items(i)), "^(.*?)\?", "", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
        lstObject.Add(oObject)
    Next

    'If we have items, add them back to the list
    If lstObject.Count > 0 Then
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        For i As Integer = 0 To lstObject.Count - 1
            ListBox1.Items.Add(lstObject.Item(i).ToString)
        Next
    End If
```